# Interactive() not working with alt.layer?

Tags: altair

I am trying to enable zooming with the mousewheel for an cartographic visualization. My code is very similar to [this symbol map example](https://uwdata.github.io/visualization-curriculum/altair_cartographic.html#symbol-maps).

However, adding `.interactive()` doesn't work when I add it to to the chart object or the layer (at the very end).

It returns an error

> Javascript Error: Expression parse error: ? {unit: "layer_0", fields: selector002_tuple_fields, values: []} : null
> This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.

Have looked in the documentation and on GitHub, but no joy. Help, anyone?

Comment: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/discussions/2485#discussioncomment-1091172. "I don't think vega-lite has any support for scale-bound selections in geographic plots, which is what .interactive() attempts to add. So no, that is not supported in Altair."

Comment: Thanks, @Mattijn. Will stop looking, then ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported in Altair as @Mattijn pointed out, see https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/679.